# Given that $\frac{2^n +1}{n^2}$ is a integer.Find $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine all set of integers $n\gt 1$ such that  $$\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}\;\;\text{  is a integer. }$$

I found that $n$ is an odd.

Please help by providing me with a hint.

Comment: A reasonable conjecture is that $n=3$ is the only solution, since it does not happen so often that $n$ is a divisor of $2^n+1$, or that $2^n+1$ is not square-free.

Comment: This is a really famous one, its the hard cousin of the ubiquitous $n| 2^n-1$. An answer can be found here: https://www.quora.com/If-n-geq-2-divides-2-n-+1-then-3-divides-n-How-can-I-prove-this. All though there are better expositions.